# Excel VBA - unselect range after paste with code using variables

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a macro to filter, copy and paste the filtered criteria into different workbooks. I cannot figure out how to unselect the range that is being pasted in within the workbooks. I have tried ".range("A1").select" , "application.cutcopymode = false". I do not know what else to try..here is my code - any insight would be helpful

```
Dim i As Long
Dim market As Variant, arrbooks() As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
market = Array(...
 ReDim arrbooks(0 To UBound(market))

'create workbooks
For i = 0 To UBound(market)
    Set arrbooks(i) = Workbooks.Add
Next

'retrieve data by autofilter

With Sheet4

    For i = 0 To UBound(market)

        .Range("H:H").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=market(i)

        .Range("H1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

       Workbooks(arrbooks(i).Name).Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll


**workbooks(arrbooks(i).name).sheets(1).application.cutcopymode = false**

        Next
End With

'save workbooks  

For i = 0 To UBound(market)

**workbooks(arrbooks(i).name).sheets(1).application.cutcopymode = false**

Workbooks(arrbooks(i).Name).SaveAs "insert save path"
Workbooks(arrbooks(i).Name).Close
Next

'clean up
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheet4.ShowAllData
Sheet4.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Sheet4.Activate
Sheet4.Range("A1").Select
```

due to compliance issues I cannot disclose the names I am filtering on

Thanks!

edit: **indicates where I tried inserting .application.cutcopymode = false

Comment: Would you show how you tried `Application.CutCopyMode = False` by inserting it again in the code?

Comment: I tried it in two places, and the macro ran both times, however when I opened the saved file - the entire pasted section was still selected. Here is both places I tried it. - I edited the original post

Comment: Type "Application.CutCopyMode = False" only, without all that "workbooks..." prefix

Comment: cutcopymode.false removes the dotted lines from a section that was setto copy.  To unselect a range simply select another, line range("A1").select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I see now what you're trying to do. It has to do with the selection in the destination, not with the `CutCopyMode`. Try

```
Application.Goto workbooks(arrbooks(i).name).sheets(1).Range("A1")
```

OTOH, `CutCopyMode` removes the "dotted" selection *of the source*, so that you cannot manually paste it again.

Answer (score 0):

see this, [Unselect column after pasting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46031866/unselect-column-after-pasting-data) i ended up selecting "A1" inorder to remove the merquri from selection area