# Unselect column after pasting data

Tags: excel, vba

this may be very simple but I am not able to work around it.

I could free up the column from where I am copying data by using `Application.CutCopyMode=False` but the column where data is pasted is still remain selected, I tried  `ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlNone` as suggested in one of the forum without any success rest of my code working fine:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim t1 As Worksheet
Dim r As Worksheet

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set t1 = Sheets("dataT1")
Set r = Sheets("HPV1report")

t1.Range("D3:CR5").Copy
r.Range("A2").PasteSpecial _
    Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
    Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, _
    Transpose:=True
    Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End sub
```

Other thing I can think of is selecting Cell A1 so the column will get free but I will prefer to use select if i can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not really un-select a cell, because it is in the nature of a worksheet that there is always a selected cell.

The only reason why there might be no selected cell is

- you select an object like a control/button, etc.
- or to protect the worksheet against user interaction like @moosli pointed out.

So the correct way to go is, as you already found out:
Select any other cell, eg. A1.

```
Worksheets("MySheet").Range("A1").Select
```

Comment: thank you for this, i had kept this option at the bottom to select "A1" inorder to remove secetion from data column, is there any other way apart from "select" to move away from column without using "select"?

Comment: @vj12 no selecting another cell than the currently selected is in deed the official way to unselect the current cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in this way

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets("name sheet selected data").Activate
Worksheets("name sheet selected data").Range("A1").Select
Worksheets("name sheet you want goto").Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Hi Jos, welcome. Please consider adding an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As PEH pointed out, there is always something selected in Excel, so he proposes to select a hardcoded cell like A1. I prefer to store the cell that is active before the copy/paste process and reselect this cell after pasting.

```
Dim ActCell As Excel.Range
Set ActCell = Excel.Application.ActiveCell
'Do the copy and paste process

Excel.Application.CutCopyMode = Excel.XlCutCopyMode.xlCut
ActCell.Select
```